# XPath attribute value in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have just started using scrapy library for web-scraping in python and I'm running into some problems.

Here's the sample xml source:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="main-box">
       ...
       ...
      <div class="heading-box">
         <h1 class="title">
             <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="London " style="width: 87px; height: 18px;">
             <cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Bridge" style="width: 69px; height: 18px;">
         </h1>
     </div>
       ...
       ...
</div>
```

I want to extract the text in the `alt` attributes in all the `cufon` tags (in this example, London Bridge).

Here's the XPath of the cufon tag as copied from `Firebug`:

`/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/cufon[1]`

Here's the code I've written:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        selector = Selector(response)

        item = SamplespiderItem()
        item['name'] = selector.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1/cufon[1]/@alt').extract()
```

From the tutorials, I read that we can use `@` to access attributes, but the output I'm getting is empty list.
Can someone help me figure this out??

Comment: How about using simpler xpath, such as : `//h1[@class='title']/cufon/@alt`?

Comment: Make sure that the HTML that is downloaded by scrapy does contain the `<cufon>` elements (remember that Scrapy does not interpret JavaScript): you can check with `scrapy shell http://www.yourdomain....` and run `response.xpath('//cufon')`

Comment: @paultrmbrth you're right. It isn't giving any response to `//cufon`. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @KrishanuKonar, hard to say without knowing the website you're targetting. You can try a JavaScript rendering option like [splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/)